# who has any idea about this error please?

Tags: solidity, truffle-contract

Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert SafeERC20: low-level call failed -- Reason given: SafeERC20: low-level call failed.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by this line (assuming you use OpenZeppelin): https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/SafeERC20.sol#L69

So the goes to the Address contract (because of the type set here https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/SafeERC20.sol#L20 ) and fails there due to some data checks. Impossible to say what the real failure reason is without analyzing all of your code.